# download and save images from a website using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, scraper

I am new to scrapy and Python, so my question may be a simple one. By using an existing website guide, I've written a scraper which scrapes a website's pages and shows the images URL, name and ... in a output file. I want to download the images in a directory but the output directory is empty!

Here is my code:

**myspider.py**

```
import scrapy
class BrickSetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'brick_spider`enter code here`'
start_urls = ['http://brickset.com/sets/year-2016']

def parse(self, response):
    SET_SELECTOR = '.set'
    for brickset in response.css(SET_SELECTOR):

        NAME_SELECTOR = 'h1 a ::text'
        PIECES_SELECTOR = './/dl[dt/text() = "Pieces"]/dd/a/text()'
        MINIFIGS_SELECTOR = './/dl[dt/text() = "Minifigs"]/dd[2]/a/text()'
        IMAGE_SELECTOR = 'img ::attr(src)'
        yield {
            'name': brickset.css(NAME_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
            'pieces': brickset.xpath(PIECES_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
            'minifigs': brickset.xpath(MINIFIGS_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
            'image': brickset.css(IMAGE_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
        }

    NEXT_PAGE_SELECTOR = '.next a ::attr(href)'
    next_page = response.css(NEXT_PAGE_SELECTOR).extract_first()
    if next_page:
        yield scrapy.Request(
            response.urljoin(next_page),
            callback=self.parse
        )
```

**settings.py**

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'brickset.pipelines.BricksetPipeline': 1}
IMAGES_STORE = '/home/nmd/brickset/brickset/spiders/output'


#items.py 
import scrapy
class BrickSetSpider(scrapy.Item):
image_urls = scrapy.Field()
images = scrapy.Field()
pass
```

Comment: You didn't show us probably the most important part here, the code for `brickset.pipelines.BricksetPipeline` class.

Comment: The code you wrote has only scraping data of website like image SRC url.so use the yeilded data and download images using wget

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy provides a media pipeline if your interested in downloading files or images

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1}
```

Then you need to add `image_urls` in your item for the pipeline to download the file, so change

```
    yield {
        'name': brickset.css(NAME_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
        'pieces': brickset.xpath(PIECES_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
        'minifigs': brickset.xpath(MINIFIGS_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
        'image': brickset.css(IMAGE_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
    }
```

to

```
    yield {
        'name': brickset.css(NAME_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
        'pieces': brickset.xpath(PIECES_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
        'minifigs': brickset.xpath(MINIFIGS_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
        'image_urls': brickset.css(IMAGE_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
    }
```

For more details refer to https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html

Comment: thanks for your attention and also fast reply @Tarun Lalwani...I chamged the yield as you said, but the problem is not solved and again i can not download the images. Should i check another functions or files for any probable problem?! thanks again :)